# Virtual Functions changing a variable C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to Stack overflow and C++ I want to be able to use a function in a different class but change a variable for the new class.

So in the code below I have the function `readfile` in the Class Business, I have a new Class Customer called by `class Customer: public Business`.

I want open a different file for each. In Business file is "Business.csv" and in Customer it is "Customer.csv" but when I call the Customer readfile, it opened the "Business.csv" file.

How can I get it to open the "Customer.csv" file? (Also, I am going to use the same function to open other files too!
Below is the Base Class

```
// Base Class Business
int Business::readfile(string file) // Read the file and store to vector
{
    // create loops to take in necessary information   
    ifstream openfile; // create instance of ofstream function For reading the file
    openfile.open(file); // Open file
    if (!openfile)
    { // check if file opened, if not return with error message
        cout << "Error, cannot open Business.txt file \n";
        return(0);
    }
    // open the file and count the number of lines so we know when to stop and where to add a new line
    while (openfile)
    {
        getline(openfile, buffer, '\n'); //Open the file and read until return
        i++; // count the number of lines
    }
    openfile.close();

    // open the file and store the data into a vector
    openfile.open(file); // Open file
    cout << file;
    for (row = 0; row<(i - 1); row++) // loop to go through rows to i
    { 
        vec.push_back(vector<string>()); //create an empty row in vector
        for (column = 0; column<j; column++) // loop to go through the columns
        {       
            getline(openfile, buffer, '\t'); // read a string until next tab
            vec[row].push_back(buffer); //add data to column of vector  

        }
        cout << setw(30) << setfill(' ') << vec[row][0]; // print data out onscreen
        getline(openfile, buffer, '\n'); // read a string until return
    }
    cout << endl;
    openfile.close();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What parameter did you pass when calling `Business::openfile()`?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Since it's supposed to be *minimal* we don't need irrelevant code, like the code to actually read the data.

Comment: Also, very important, if you want to override a function from a base class, remember to mark that function as `virtual` in the base class. Or you won't really be overriding but shadowing it.

Comment: seems unnecessary to read the file twice, just do getline and then push_back on your vector and you are set. e.g. `while (openfile)
    {
        getline(openfile, buffer, '\n');
        vec.push_back(buffer);
    }`

Comment: Martin Zhai - do you mean Business::readfile(string file)? if so then I have a string variable file in Business and Customer Classes, they have different values and that's what I want to use but it always just uses the Base class Business value

Comment: Edd, I had declared the Function as virtual in the Header file but still only reads the file variable of the base class.

Comment: Some Programmer dude. Not sure what you mean? Does this make more sense?

    class Business
    {
 // Variables
   private:  // variables only used within class
string file = "Business.csv";
public:
 int openbusiness();  // call the function to check if there is a file
};
int Business::readfile(string file) // Read the file and store to vector
{
 openfile.open(file); // Open file
}
class Customer: public Business
{
 // Variables
private:  // variables only used within class
 string file = "Customer.csv";
}

Customer C1; 
C1.readfile("Customer.csv");